# creating a record with has_one and belongs_to

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, belongs-to, has-one

I have a User and a Team model. A user can only have one team and each team belongs to a user. I'm struggling to get the association to work both ways.

Team model:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :team
end
```

I've added a team_id column to the users table and user_id to a teams table.

I want to create a team for the user so in the console I did the following

```
@user = User.find_by(id: 4)
@team = @user.build_team
```

Which created a team with the correct user_id but the team_id for the user is still nil. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to delete this question as it's probably pretty stupid, but in case any one else gets as confused as me I found the answer here: http://ruby-on-rails.wonderhowto.com/how-to/use-one-one-association-when-using-ruby-rails-3-407824/

What I now understand is that you have a has_one relationship and the foreign key appears in the table of the Model that it 'owns'. I.e. a user has_one team so the teams table needs a user_id. The users table does not need a team_id.

You can create a new team by using

```
@team = @user.build_team
```

As I did or:

```
@user.team = (name: "blah", rating: "blah blah")
```

and then if you want to get the teams user then

```
@user.team
```

will return that object.